# ¿Porqué no me aparece google_maps_api.xml cuando abro un nuevo proyecto de maps?

Tags: java, android, google-maps, google-api

me estoy iniciando en esto de la programación y tengo una duda.

Cuando abro un nuevo proyecto con la plantilla de google maps, no me aparece el google_maps_api.xml, si no que me aparece el android manifest. En los tutoriales que he visto (unos 2 o 3) al crear el proyecto les aparecía esa pestaña, me gustaría saber como hacer para que a mi también me aparezca. por si es relevante, tengo la API key.

Muchas gracias! [image: captura de pantalla]

Comment: Yo siempre que he trabajado con la Api de Google Maps he tenido que definir en el archivo local.properties mi Api-key nunca he tenido ningun xml llamado "google_api_key". Comprueba la fecha de los videos porque alomejor antes el funcionamiento era diferente.

Comment: El archivo google_maps_api.xml solo se genera automaticamente si usas la platilla de "Google Maps Activity" https://i.stack.imgur.com/dfRYE.png , revisa la respuesta https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/527925/95

Comment: holaa, yo tambien sigo con esa duda, sabes como agregar esa plantilla en android studio

Comment: otra pregunta que pena molestar en lo que creo la API KEY me pide huella y nombre del paquete cual puedo agregar o donde lo puedo ver dentro del proyecto

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si tienes tu  API Key, agrega esta definición debes agregarla dentro de tu archivo `AndroidManifest.xml` , agregando una referencia a tu archivo `strings.xml`:

```
   <application>
   ...
   ...
   <meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
    android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />
   ...
   ...
   </application>
```

Dentro de strings.xml define el API KEY

Definir el valor de la API Key en tu archivo `/res/values/strings.xml` , ejemplo:

```
<resources>

    <string name="google_maps_key">xJADASBRENBESDASGTEBTRNRTNREENTENTEWESAASSA</string>

</resources>
```

---

Si deseas usar el archivo `google_maps_api.xml`, Android Studio incluye una plantilla de `Google Maps Activity`.

[image: Jorgesys Map activity]

Si seleccionas esta plantilla, el código de la plantilla incluye un archivo `google_maps_api.xml`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

que contiene una [enlace que simplifica la obtención de una clave API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/start#get-key) la cual definirìas dentro del archivo  `google_maps_api.xml` en la siguiente entrada:

```
 <string name="google_maps_key" templateMergeStrategy="preserve" translatable="false">API KEY</string>
```

Cualquiera de las dos opciones son vàlidas, te sugiero revisar:

[**Cómo usar claves de API**](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/get-api-key?hl=es-419)

Answer (score 0):

Antes Android studio te creaba el archivo que comentas y tu también lo puedes hacer si quieres, hasta donde yo sé hay 3 posibles formas para trabajar con tu API_KEY y todas son válidas.

### 1. API_KEY en el Manifest

Directamente dentro de tu etiqueta xml `aplication` puedes introducir el siguiente código:

```
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
    android:value="tu_api_key"/>
```

### 2. API_KEY en local.properties##

En tu archivo local.properties puedes introducir
`MAPS_API_KEY=tu_api_key`
y luego en tu manifest

```
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
    android:value="${MAPS_API_KEY}"/>
```

### 3. google_maps_api.xml

antes era así como se hacía y por eso lo ves en los tutoriales.

El método 2 es lo recomendado y lo que vas a ver en la documentación oficial de Google Maps y también puedes utilizar un string en tu fichero string.xml para tu api_key pero yo no lo recomiendo ya que esta pensado para traducciones, un saludo.